# Windows Remote Assistance Android client?

Tags: android, networking, remote-access, remote-desktop

I am searching for RA client on Android platform.
Main aim I pursue is to be able to start RA session with PC that run Windows 8.1 Pro x64. Session should be started in a standard MS-native way (like *msra.exe* on desktop).

Expected hardware environment:
*Client side*: Android Phone ([Samsung Galaxy S Relay](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s_relay_4g_t699-4914.php)) with CM11 firmware
*Server side*: MS Windows 8.1 x64 Pro Mini-PC

UPDATE
@Bogdan Bogdanov
I tried connecting through [Android RDP app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.android&hl=en) and **didn't succeed**. Please, provide only stable and proven solutions. Or provide exact settings you changed in RDP app to be able to connect to RA sessions.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. What are your requirements? As I wrote on ASE, there's a [section on Windows remote control apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controlpc#group_656) on my site. If those "can't get through", it might be your router/firewall blocking access.

Comment: Sorry @Suncatcher. I did not understand that you require `RDP protocol`. I just try *Microsoft Remote Desktop* and it works fine. I suppose some network restriction (as @Izzy suggested). I will delete my answer though, because it not useful to you.